# How to assign a specific domain to all my links on my page in HTML?

Tags: html, environment

Hello I am making a static web page, and I need to put a specifig domain to all the links on my page, for example

Example:

From this

```
<a href="/courses.html">courses</a>
```

To something like this

```
<a href="http://www.bigschool.com/courses.html">courses</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you are using pure HTML, you can try to manually enable the `base` tag by following sample code:

```
<head>
    <base href="http://www.bigschool.com/" target="_blank">
</head>
```

Detail please read [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp).